# how to convert .m4a to .mp3 using swift2?

Tags: ios, mp3, swift2, m4a

How do I convert a .m4a (it's a voice memo) to .mp3?
I've researced around and I've seen people mention Lame, AudioConverter, but can't figure out how I make it work?

if anybody has a samplecode, I would love to see something!

Comment: try just changing the extension to mp3.

Comment: that doesn't work, already tried that